# android-How to make an animation lines in a circle light or dark

Tags: android, android-animation, android-image

I want to have something like this :
[image]

as you can see, there are some lines that are light and some of them are dark .

How can I turn them light or dark in android ? What should I do ?

Comment: 9Patches and the standard Android animation framework come to mind

Answer (score 3):

**here is some libraries that could help you to achieve that :**

https://github.com/Todd-Davies/ProgressWheel

https://github.com/f2prateek/progressbutton?source=c

https://github.com/castorflex/SmoothProgressBar

https://github.com/dmytrodanylyk/circular-progress-button

https://github.com/FilipPudak/ProgressPieView

**tutorial to create your own circular progress bar**:

http://www.truiton.com/2013/06/android-circular-progress-bar

**creating circular progress bar with unity:**

http://www.theappguruz.com/sample-code/circular-progress-bar/

Good luck.